# Free non-consumable in-app purchases with ios

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect, storekit

I recently noticed that there is a free tier for non-consumable in-app purchases on iTunesConnect. However, I have seen conflicting reports about whether purchases function the same when prices are set to this tier. Can someone clarify a few points?

- What happens when setting an existing purchase to the free tier?
- Are new purchases approved when set as free?
- (Bonus) How long has this free tier for non-consumables existed?

Comment: Answering my own question, but we've had luck getting them approved and purchased. Will leave open for any further answers and insight.

Answer (score 0):

> What happens when setting an existing purchase to the free tier?

Purchase go through as normal, users are just charged for $0. The purchase goes on their purchase history which can be restored.

> Are new purchases approved when set as free?

Yes. I've done so. IAP price is something you can change all the time.

> How long has this free tier for non-consumables existed?

No idea. Android still doesn't have it though